# How to best structure a database while keeping track of dataset changes

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got a small CRM and I'm trying to figure out the best way to designing the DB tables.

I've currently got a single table for users that got around 30 columns which I alter from time to time. Since I am storing two different information on that table (user + company information) I was thinking of splitting that table into 3 (user + company + connection between these 2) but I am also interested in keeping a copy of any changes that are being made in these rows.

So going from:

```
user_id | firstname | last_name | company_name | company_city | company_subject | rank | status
 1      |   John    |  Borrows  |  Boink INC   |      NY      |      Web dev    |  1   |   1
 2      |   Mike    |  Smith    |  Smithin INC |      OC      |      Laywer     |  1   |   2
 3      |   Mary    |  Anton    |    Caffin    |      SJ      |      Moving     |  2   |   1
```

to something like this

```
user_id | firstname | last_name | rank | status
 1      |   John    |  Borrows  |  1   |   1
 2      |   Mike    |  Smith    |  1   |   2
 3      |   Mary    |  Anton    |  2   |   1

comp_id | company_name | company_city | company_subject
 1      |  Boink INC   |      NY      |      Web dev
 2      |  Smithin INC |      OC      |      Laywer
 3      |    Caffin    |      SJ      |      Moving

con_id | user_id | comp_id
1      | 1       | 1
2      | 2       | 2
3      | 3       | 3
```

But I'm not sure how to track the changes when for example a user changes the company name or some other info on user's table etc.

Comment: what do you mean by keeping a copy of any changes? what would be the changes?

Comment: @whisk For example a user updates his user info (which also includes phone number, address, etc etc) I'd like to keep a copy of the old records too. (to avoid double registrations etc)

Comment: Sometimes I've just juggled prior data to a history table, so the 'main' table only contains one entry for a user (for a simple example). Then the history table is there for record keeping. However when GDPR hit, we are now purging all that history when it is stale by 6 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the normalization rules for structuring your database tables. You will find anything you need for that by just searching for database normalization.

Regarding your "update-history" you could add a Timestamp to your datasets and/or a separate boolean field "outdated" to be able to filter out the latest information.
Would be the simplest solution that comes into my mind.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about the structure. Could you please give me an example of your update-history solution? Thanks!

Comment: If you just add a column with a Timestamp (when the dataset was created) you will be able to get the newest dataset but still have the old ones stored. Additionally, you could add a boolean column with "outdated" and set that to true, as soo as you add a newer dataset.
It might be good to store the old datasets in a separate table, so you have a table for all current data and a similar table where you store the old data. Just move the old ones to the other table as soon as you create new ones.
I don't know if there is a more fancy solution to this, but this way it would be pretty simple.